# Binding Variables in Ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, binding

I currently have a table that is listed as follows:

```
projects = Project.find(:all, :conditions => [conditions + "AND (name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?)", "%#{params[:query]}%", "%#{params[:query]}%"])
```

where

```
 conditions = Project.in_used_projects(:alias => "projects")
```

However I need to include a 3rd variable which is not from the Project table but from a Tags table. The column I need is `Tag - > Names`. Is there anyway I can bind variables from another table in Ruby? The `Project.find(all)` automatically passes the `SELECT * FROM Project` into MYSQL. Someone has suggested using a join function, but I'm not sure how this would work. Any ideas?

**EDIT 1**

I have tried the suggested answer of using

```
projects = Project.find(:all, :joins => "tags", :conditions => [conditions + "AND (projects.name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? OR tags.name LIKE ?", ["%#{params[:query]}%" * 3]].flatten)
```

but now I am getting another error

`Mysql::Error: Unknown table 'projects': SELECT`projects`.* FROM`projects`tags WHERE ((projects.status = 2)AND (projects.name LIKE '%%' OR projects.description LIKE '%%' OR tags.name LIKE '%%')`

Very strange considering the projects table exists. Why isn't Ruby recognizing it now that i've included another table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it was just a simple syntax error

```
projects = Project.find(:all, :joins=>:tags, :conditions => [conditions + "AN    rojects.name LIKE ? OR projects.description LIKE ? OR tags.name LIKE ?)", "%#    ams[:query]}%", "%#{params[:query]}%", "%#{params[:query]}%"])
```

is the correct syntax. The :joins needs to be followed by :tags, not by "tags"
Thanks again for everyone's help

Answer (score 2):

Try this out for size:

```
projects = Project.find(:all, :joins => "tags", :conditions => [conditions + "AND (projects.name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? OR tags.name LIKE ?", ["%#{params[:query]}%" * 3]].flatten)
```

The `:joins` option tells Active Record to perform an SQL join onto the `tags` table, which will allow you to perform queries on the tags column. Also take note in this example how I've added the `projects.` prefix to your original `name` column. This is so your database doesn't get confused what `name` column you want; the one from the  `projects` or the `tags` table.

Comment: Mysql::Error: Unknown table 'projects': SELECT `projects`.* FROM `projects`  tags WHERE ((projects.status = 2)AND (projects.name LIKE '%%' OR projects.description LIKE '%%' OR tags.name LIKE '%%')

Comment: projects = Project.find(:all, :joins => "tags", :conditions => [conditions + "AND (projects.name LIKE ? OR projects.description LIKE ? OR tags.name LIKE ?)", "%#{params[:query]}%", "%#{params[:query]}%", "%#{params[:query]}%" ].flatten)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any relationship between projects and tags? If the reason for your query is that there is, it should be reflected in the model (for ex with a HABTM), which would also enable you to easily filter based on that relationship without the need to have complex SQL queries crafted.

Comment: nope no relationships. the tags table is only used for once in the site and its for site admin purposes.